# can't login after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Can't login with my working password after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04. Pretty desperate at this point. Would like to know how those b.., who were insisting on this upgrade, feel about this - first, and how to downgrade back to 16.04 rather than dealing with so poorly designed 18.04. Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the error, what happens exactly? If I were to guess, I'd say you probably have some broken packages so switch to a TTY, e.g. use Ctrl + Alt + F3, login to the command line there, then runs "sudo apt install -f" and see if that helps.

Comment: Try logging in TTY mode. If you can log in, this means your password is correct. Then use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Also, if you don't like GNOME on Ubuntu you can go back to Unity. Since in my opinion the only way to downgrade is clean install.

Comment: You are likely to get more and better help without the ranting.

Comment: Can I make a 'wild guess' you are one of those who don't care of their bad 'professional reputation'? Relax and keep your attitude to yourself. Thank you in advance

Comment: Dear All, thank you for generously sharing with me your expertise through your constructive responses. I'll try everything you suggested, and I'll keep you posted with my results. Thank you again.

Comment: Don't you occasionally have a Dell laptop, where 16.04 was preinstalled? If so, they screwed it up by preinstalling a AMDGPU-pro driver, which simply stops building after upgrade. This is more of a dell problem, you can fix it by removing amdgpu-pro package from a tty.